# User Notice: Required @OA\PathItem() not found : symfony 4

Tags: symfony, openapi, swagger-php, nelmioapidocbundle, symfony-4.4

[image]I m using symfony 4.4 / nelmio api doc bundle 4.0 / zircote swagger-php 3.0.
When i try with a first example i get this error : User Notice: Required @OA\PathItem() not found

```
namespace App\Controller;

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

/**

@OA\PathItem(
path="/products/{product_id}",
@OA\Parameter(ref="#/components/parameters/product_id_in_path_required")
)
*/
class ProductController
{

/**
* @OA\Get(
*   tags={"Products"},
*   path="/products/{product_id}",
*   @OA\Response(
*       response="default",
*       description="successful operation",
*       @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/responses/product")
*   )
* )
*/
public function getProduct($id)
{
}

}
```

https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/3.0.0/Examples/example-object/example-object.php
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/3.0.0/Examples/using-refs/ProductController.php

Comment: What exactly do you try? And can you share the full and exact error message?

Comment: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/3.0.0/Examples/using-refs/ProductController.php

Comment: i have tried without PathItem but the error still here :

`namespace App\Controller;

use OpenApi\Annotations as OA;

class ProductController
{

/**
 * @OA\Get(
 *   tags={"Products"},
 *   path="/products/{product_id}",
 *   @OA\Response(
 *       response="default",
 *       description="successful operation",
 *       @OA\JsonContent(ref="#/components/responses/product")
 *   )
 * )
 */
public function getProduct($id)
{
}

}`

Comment: I tried with examples :
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/3.0.0/Examples/example-object/example-object.php
https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/3.0.0/Examples/using-refs/ProductController.php